Ramsey's Theorem and Weihrauch reducibility
Let $\text{RT}^n_k$ denote (infinite) Ramsey's theorem for $n$-tuples and $k$ colors. Let $\leq_W$ denote Weihrauch (i.e., uniform) reducibility.
It is known that, for fixed $k \geq 2$, if $n > m \geq 2$, then $\text{RT}^m_k \lneq_W \text{RT}^n_k$ (pages 5 and 6 of this paper).
It is also known that, for fixed $n \geq 2$, if $k > j \geq 2$, then $\text{RT}^n_j \lneq_W \text{RT}^n_k$ (Theorem 3.3 of that same paper).
Thus, we have this picture, where each arrow denotes a strict Weihrauch reducibility:
What can we say about other potential reducibilites beyond those shown in the picture? In other words, for $n > m \geq 2$ and $k > j \geq 2$, might either of the following hold?

$\text{RT}^n_j \leq_W \text{RT}^m_k$
$\text{RT}^m_k \leq_W \text{RT}^n_j$


You might want to take a look at [1], it contains a large number of results on the many versions of Ramsey's theorem.
In particular, by Corollary 4.21, for every $m\ge 1$ and every $k$, $\mathsf{RT}^m_k <_\mathrm{W} \mathsf{RT}^{m+1}_2$, which answers both of your questions.
[1]: Brattka, Vasco; Rakotoniaina, Tahina, On the uniform computational content of Ramsey’s theorem, J. Symb. Log. 82, No. 4, 1278-1316 (2017). ZBL1422.03132.
